# Why is "error: illegal start of simple expression" for reduceByKey?

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to scala and spark and while implementing reduceByKey  i got the below error.

```
var redRdd = filterRdd.reduceByKey((acc , val) => if (acc > val ) acc else val)
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
var redRdd = filterRdd.reduceByKey((acc , val) => if (acc > val ) acc else val)
```

filterRdd is just (order_id, Amount) tuple.

```
scala> filterRdd.first
res10: (Int, Double) = (1,299.98)
```

I want to first  get the max value per partition and then reduce output from all partitions.
can someone help me in understanding why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

val is a key word in scala and you cannot have a variable named as val. Change the val to v it will work.

```scala
 var redRdd = filterRdd.reduceByKey((acc , v) => if (acc > v ) acc else v)
```

It will work.

And you could use `math.max(acc,v)` instead of the if else.

Comment: Thanks @Knight71 . I should not use  built in , Thanks a lot.
Can you help me in finding min   using above technique.

Comment: As Accumulator  is always initialized to 0 then i can not compare it to get the min value . Can you gave me some hints .

Comment: what is accumulator here ? reduceByKey examples http://dmtolpeko.com/2015/02/12/multi-column-key-and-value-reduce-a-tuple-in-spark/

Comment: Kindly correct me if i have wrong understanding about this  upto my understanding `reduceByKey((acc , v) => if (acc > v ) acc else v)`
acc is global variable every time a value is added to acc and acc is passed as map red output to passsed to reduce function.

Comment: yes you are right but the acc is not initialized to zero , it is initialized to the first element of the map side combine. So you can use math.min(acc,v) to get the minimum value of key.

Comment: Thanks you @Knight71 for the detailed explanation it helped me a lot